# Webdriver manager from behind a firewall

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I'm trying to use Webdriver manager from behind a firewall.

It works, but only allows to access sites that are on internet.
For those on intranet I have :"ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED"

I think that it's able to use the proxy to check for the correct version of the ChromeDriver, but the way I configured it, it also forces all traffic to go through that firewall which doesn't work for intranet.

There is a .pac file where I extracted the organisation firewall address from. Ideally it should probably better to use that .pac file instead

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.core.download_manager import WDMDownloadManager
from webdriver_manager.core.http import HttpClient
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from requests import Response
import urllib3
import requests
import os
import time
os.environ['WDM_SSL_VERIFY'] = '0'
capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

PROXY = "http:// *proxy adress*"
opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opt.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
opt.add_argument("ignore-certificate-errors")
opt.add_argument(f'user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\ *Location of the Chrome profile*')

class CustomHttpClient(HttpClient):
    def get(self, url, params=None) -> Response:
        proxies={'http': 'http:// *proxy adress*',
         'https': 'http:// *proxy adress*',
         }
        return requests.get(url, params,proxies=proxies,verify=False)

http_client = CustomHttpClient()
download_manager = WDMDownloadManager(http_client)`


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager(download_manager=download_manager).install()),options=opt)`
```